# Puphpet/Vagrant: Virtual Hosts stopped working, can't access VM using network IP

Tags: vagrant, virtualhost, puppet, portforwarding

I've been using Puphpet.com to generate some Debian LAMP development machines. Everything was working great, until for no reason I couldn't reach the VM using the virtual host. Before you ask, yes, the virtual host is added to my hosts file.

Before this stopped working, I was able to access VM's virtual host in my local browser using `http://cats.dev`. Now this stopped working. The VM IP is `192.168.10.1`, which responds to the `ping` command, but doesn't show anything in the browser.

Apache and the virtual host are working ok because I can `curl localhost`, `curl 192.168.10.1` from the VM and I get the index.html content.

So it's definitely something with networking and/or port-forwarding. What could be the issue?

Here's the puphpet config.yaml

```
---
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/debian75-x64
        box_url: puphpet/debian75-x64
        hostname: null
        memory: '512'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.10.1
            forwarded_port:
                mdlnOcwbVdwF:
                    host: '9936'
                    guest: '22'
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
                setextradata:
                    VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root: 1
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: manifest.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            RI2jrQZgnFAS:
                source: ./
                target: /var/www
                nfs: 'false'
        usable_port_range: 2200..2250
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    packages: {  }
    dot_files:
        -
            bash_aliases: null
    _prevent_empty: ''
mailcatcher:
    install: 0
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/bin
        log_path: /var/log/mailcatcher/mailcatcher.log
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - php
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        4a8z4EdDCFLv:
            servername: cats.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.cats.dev
            docroot: /var/www/cats
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            override:
                - All
            options:
                - Indexes
                - FollowSymLinks
                - MultiViews
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
    mod_spdy: 0
nginx:
    install: 0
    vhosts:
        ddFCwkmxJT60:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome.dev
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '54'
    composer: '1'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
            - curl
            - gd
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: America/Chicago
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
drush:
    install: 0
    settings:
        drush.tag_branch: 6.x
mysql:
    install: '1'
    root_password: '123'
    phpmyadmin: 0
    adminer: '1'
    databases:
        CSp3erZWuecz:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: cats
            host: localhost
            user: cats
            password: '123'
            sql_file: ''
postgresql:
    install: 0
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: 0
    root_password: '123'
    phpmyadmin: 0
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
    version: '10.0'
mongodb:
    install: 0
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: 0
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
beanstalkd:
    install: 0
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: 0
    settings:
        port: '5672'
```

Comment: Oh come on, there are tons of vagrant questions. It's related to programming. Don't be such rule nazis...

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be ideal but you can vagrant ssh into your box and then edit the default.conf file. It should be in /etc/apache2/sites-available I believe. You will need to wrap <> tags around the directory tag, I was not sure how to show that in the example below.

```
  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/cats"

  ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www
   Directory "/var/www/cats"
```